# Using firebase in react-native (expo) app for Web as well as Mobile

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

Our App needs to work on Web (PWA) as well as Android and iOS. Currently, the same codebase works because we use the Javascript Web SDK. If we move to react-native-firebase (because SDK 48 no longer supports Firebase Recaptcha for Phone based Authentication), does it mean 2 separate codebases now - one for web and other for mobile apps? I am assuming here that react-native-firebase won't compile for RNweb. If there a way to have both libraries live inside the same app? Also, what would be a good way to structure code in such a case?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet :(